# AWS S3 lambda function doesn't trigger when upload large file

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have 2 buckets on the S3 service. I have a lambda function "create-thumbnail" that triggered when an object is created into an original bucket, if it is an image, then resize it and upload it into the resized bucket.

Everything is working fine, but the function doesn't trigger when I upload files more than 4MB on the original bucket.

Function configurations are as follow,

- Timeout Limit: 2mins
- Memory 10240
- Trigger Event type: ObjectCreated (that covers create, put, post, copy and multipart upload complete)

Comment: Does it works fine with small files? Have you checked logs? What error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine with small files.

Comment: Does the Monitoring tab of the Lambda function show any invocations or errors? Also, check the CloudWatch Logs (accessible from the same tab) to see whether the function was started. It might be running out of memory or hitting a timeout for large objects.

Comment: There are no invocations for large files. But invocations for small file are listed

Comment: When I add that large file in test Event, then it works. But it doesn't work when I upload a file from my application

Comment: @ShaileshMishra Have you tested to upload file on s3 instead of TestEvent, does it is working?

Comment: @dahiya_boy I just tried that, it still doesn't work. The function doesn't invoke

Comment: I have added a temporary solution for this issue. While uploading files from my application, I am uploading files on both buckets, so that at least I can get files from resized bucket even if the function didn't trigger. If the function gets triggered, the image will get resized and overwrite in the bucket.

Comment: @ShaileshMishra This is not a solution. i suggest you to create 1 sample lambda and make all connection or config, print hello world if file is upload. Now do step to step (add lambda code) and keep checking, I am pretty sure you will find the hole.

Comment: @dahiya_boy thanks for the guidance, but the function is not getting invoke with a large file. Even log is also not maintained.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact event configuration in the bucket? I suspect that larger files are uploaded using `Multipart` APIs. Your event might only "listen" to `s3:PutObject` but not for things like `s3:CompleteMultipartUpload`? This might be a long shot, but worth a try.

Comment: @Jens My event configuration is "All object create event" that includes 
PUT, POST, COPY, Multipart upload completed
And on configuration tab, it says "Event type: ObjectCreated"

Comment: @ShaileshMishra I am facing exactly the same problem. I tried it with specific event listeners and also with the global "s3:ObjectCreated" one. I did not think that it is really a bug of AWS - but it seems to me. Also I would expect, that many more are stumbling a cross this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the lambda function, I have used some packages on the server and resize the file accordingly and then upload those files on the S3 bucket.
I know this is not a solution to this question, but that's the only solution I found

Thanks to everyone who took their time to investigate this.